# Changing WSM(WAVE Short Message) packet size in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, 802.11p

Does setting length of WSM via `setWsmLength` or adding a large payload via `setWsmData` makes any difference during simulation? I am trying to simulate a heavily used network, but changing any of those two values doesn't seem to make any difference. I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/Nm6ehfUgbZs), but wanted to confirm this. And If I wanted to change the size of the WSM do I have to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a packet for your application in a `.msg` file as follows:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage_m.h"
}}

class WaveShortMessage;

message MyAppsPacket extends WaveShortMessage {
    string sourceAddress;           
    string destinationAddress;      
    simtime_t sendingTime;
}
```

Then in your code you can use the built-in `setByteLength()`. Use [cPacket](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classcPacket.html) subclass for your messages because:

> (cPacket is) A subclass of cMessage that can be used to represent packets
>   (frames,  * datagrams, application messages, etc). cPacket adds length
>   (measured in  * bits or bytes), bit error flag, and encapsulation
>   capability to cMessage.  * Length and bit error flag are significant
>   when the packet travels through  * a cDatarateChannel or another
>   channel that supports data rate and/or  * error modelling.  *

Related [Q&A](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/Vo-fK-gaK9U) which shows the casting from `cMessage` to `cPacket`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is decades later, but maybe it can help some new vanets lovers like me.

In omnet++5.4.1 and Veins 4.7.1, in the function

> populateWSM()

defined in BaseWaveApplLayer.cc (veins/modules/application/ieee80211p), you can set the bit length with the

> wsm->setBitLength()

method and it changes the size of the wsm packet. By default, it has the length of the header

> wsm->setBitLength(headerLength)

I have played with this and could obtain different packet sizes.

Hope this is useful.