# Changing length of WAVE message(VEINS/OMNET++)

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins

How to change the length of the WAVE message. Method `setWsmLength` doesn't work. From the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564083/changing-wsmwave-short-message-packet-size-in-veins) I gather that it is not possible, as the functionality is not implemented in WAVE. But the answer provided is very vague. It asks to create a .msg file, which is clear. But the rest is not very clear. Can somebody clarify or explain it?

P.S: I couldn't comment in that thread, so had to ask new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WaveShortMessage` is an `OMNeT++` packet, so one can always use `addByteLength()` to increase its existing size or `setByteLength()` to set a new size of it, description in `OMNeT++` [manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec215). Defining a new message is not necessary.
An example:

```
WaveShortMessage* wsm = prepareWSM("data", dataLengthBits, channel, dataPriority, -1,2);
wsm->setWsmData(blockedRoadId.c_str());
int byteLen = blockedRoadId.length(); // assuming that one char = one byte
wsm->addByteLength(byteLen);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried doing it but it somehow doesn't change the result. I have set Veins channel capacity to 3Mbps, and I am trying to overload the system. But now matter how big I set the packet size, the system never gets overloaded. Might the problem be that Veins doesn't simulate the size change of packets?

Comment: Veins sends a `WaveShortMessage` in every `beaconInterval` period. By default `beaconInterval` is equal to 1 s. In order to consume 3 Mbps bandwidth by one car you should set size to ... approx. 370 kilobytes! So try to decrease `beaconInterval` in `omnetpp.ini`.