# Create a WSM inherented message

Tags: omnet++, veins

I would like to make a new message type called `wsm_info`.

In this message type, I want to include a vehicle structure, as it follows:

```
struct vehicle{
   int vehicle_id;
   Coord vehicle_pos;
   float speed;
};
```

In the veins example there is a function called: `prepareWSM` that's declared in `BaseWaveApplLayer.h`. This function is a `virtual WaveShortMessage*` type.

If the  `wsm_info` was inherented from `WaveShortMessage` I wouldn't need to write and declare a new `prepareWSM` for `wsm_info`, right?

So how can I make this `wsm_info` message inherented of `WaveShortMessage`?

I tried to write like this in the `wsm_info.h`:

```
class wsm_info : public WaveShortMessage
```

Instead of, that was written previously:

```
class wsm_info : public ::omnetpp::cPacket
```

But the error that I get is the following one:

```
cannot initialize a variable of type wsm_info * with an rvalue of type WaveShortMessage
```

The full code of my msg_info is below:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"
#include "veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage_m.h"
}}

class noncobject Coord;

class WaveShortMessage;

struct vehicle {
        int vehicle_id;
        Coord vehicle_pos;
        float speed;
    };

message wsm_info extends WaveShortMessage {
    //Version of the Wave Short Message
    int wsmVersion = 0;
    //Determine which security mechanism was used
    int securityType = 0;
    //Channel Number on which this packet was sent
    int channelNumber;
    //Data rate with which this packet was sent
    int dataRate = 1;
    //Power Level with which this packet was sent
    int priority = 3;
    //Unique number to identify the service
    int psid = 0;
    //Provider Service Context
    string psc = "Service with some Data";
    //Length of Wave Short Message
    int wsmLength;

    vehicle data;

    int senderAddress = 0;
    int recipientAddress = -1;
    int serial = 0;
    Coord senderPos;
    simtime_t timestamp = 0;
}
```

Can anyone take a look on my code and point me where is wrong and why? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `msg_info.msg` should have the following content:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage_m.h"
}}

class noncobject Coord;

struct vehicle {
   int vehicle_id;
   Coord vehicle_pos;
   float speed;
};

class WaveShortMessage;

packet wsm_info extends WaveShortMessage {
    vehicle data;
}
```

You cannot use `prepareWSM()` because it creates a `WaveShortMessage` object which cannot be cast to `wsm_info`. Instead you may write a new method, for example:

1. In `/veins/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h` add:

   ```
   #include "veins/modules/messages/wsm_info_m.h"
   ```

   and in the class add the declaration:

   ```
   wsm_info* prepare_wsm_info(std::string name, int dataLengthBits, t_channel channel, int priority, int rcvId, int serial=0);
   ```
2. In `/veins/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc` add:

   ```
   wsm_info*  BaseWaveApplLayer::prepare_wsm_info(std::string name, int lengthBits, t_channel channel, int priority, int rcvId, int serial) {
   wsm_info* wsm = new wsm_info(name.c_str());
   // ... content similar to prepareWSM()
   }
   ```
3. In order to set `vehicle` structure you can just write:

   ```
   wsm_info* info = prepare_wsm_info(/* parameters */);
   vehicle veh;
   veh.speed = 60;
   veh.vehicle_id = 3;
   // ...

   info->setData(veh);
   ```

Alternatively you can add parameters for `vehicle` in the definition of `prepare_wsm_info()`.

Answer (score 4):

If i get you right, you want to extend your wsm_info.msg, is that correct?

According to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564083/changing-wsmwave-short-message-packet-size-in-veins?rq=1) question, you can modify your wsm_info.msg in the following way:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage_m.h"
}}

class WaveShortMessage;

message wsm_info extends WaveShortMessage {
   int vehicle_id;
   Coord vehicle_pos;
   float speed;
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but still get the same error when I try to build the project: `cannot initialize a variable of type wsm_info * with an rvalue of type WaveShortMessage`. It happens when `wsm_info* wsm = prepareWSM("data",dataLengthBits, channel, dataPriority, -1,2)`

Answer (score 0):

where must be declare wsm_info.msg ?in which folder?

Comment: `veins-veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/messages/msg_info.msg`

Comment: i want to create a packet collector with a specific structure,is it true that i must define a packet collector.msg like msg_info.msg and define my variables and extend from waveshortmessage.is it true? where must be add this:"and in the class add the declaration: 'code' wsm_info* prepare_wsm_info(std::string name, int dataLengthBits, t_channel channel, int priority, int rcvId, int serial=0);' "pb772"

Comment: there are three files: msg_info.msg, msg_info.h (in this file there are msg_info functions definitions), msg_info.cc(in this file, functions declarations)

Comment: is it true that in BaseWaveApplLayer.h in protected add this? `virtual PacketCollector* prepareWSM(std::string name, int dataLengthBits, t_channel channel, int priority, int rcvId, int serial=0);` @pb772