# how to get Frame Id in BaseWaveApplLayer class veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am implementing ACK functionality to be sent by RSU and I am trying to get `frameID` in `BaseWaveApplLayer` class. It has `cMessage` object but I am unable to get correct freamID
I tried to use `messageId` but it is different than the sent from nodes. Also tested the `getEncapsulationId()` but that is as well different. How can I get `frameId` sent by sender?

```
void BaseWaveApplLayer::handleLowerMsg(cMessage* msg) {
    WaveShortMessage* wsm = dynamic_cast<WaveShortMessage*>(msg);
    ASSERT(wsm);
    if (BasicSafetyMessage* bsm = dynamic_cast<BasicSafetyMessage*>(wsm)) {
        receivedBSMs++;
        onBSM(bsm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to set the ID at the sender side, then you will be able to access the ID as at the receiver. To do so you will have to extend the message definition in the `*.msg` file to have a new field to store the ID for your application. That can be called `myAppsId`, for example.

Note how [this](https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/blob/master/veins/src/veins/modules/heterogeneous/messages/HeterogeneousMessage.msg) implementation extends the `WaveShortMessage` with new fields.

You can use the same approach to extend `WaveShortMessage` and create a new message type for your application with the desired fields. Or you can directly modify the definition of the `WaveShortMessage`.

Then basically use the `set()` and `get()` functions for the newly defined field on the sending and receiving side, respectively.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35576940/4786271) is a useful solution for a different purpose, but the same applies to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: @Sam1324 if the solution works, accept it for future reference